# Two separate tables, how to check if user is owner of updating other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have to tables
One with users
Other with images

They both have one column in common which is the 'type', for example "landscape"

How do I update a row in images only if the person who login has the same 'type' as the image

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET display=? WHERE id =?";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($action, $id));
```

That works now I just need to add security so not any user can update any row.
In my session I have 'type', do i just make another query that gets the 'type' from images then compare and keep them seperate?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this based on the user data of the logged-in user.

```
$sql = "UPDATE images SET display=? WHERE id =? AND type=?";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($action, $id, $user_data->type));
```

It's a bit more secure but users from the same type can still update all the images, maybe that's correct behavior. If not, define via another query which user can access/update a image.